# Why Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255) != Color.White?

Tags: .net, gdi+

Why Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255) is **not** equal to Color.White ? Is there any built-in way to compare only A,R,G,B values and not color names?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03x8ct2(VS.85).aspx

> This structure only does comparisons
>   with other Color structures. To
>   compare colors based solely on their
>   ARGB values, you should use the ToArgb
>   method. This is because the Equals and
>   op_Equality members determine
>   equivalency using more than just the
>   ARGB value of the colors. For example,
>   Black and FromArgb(0,0,0) are not
>   considered equal, since Black is a
>   named color and FromArgb(0,0,0) is
>   not.

Comment: Just to add to this the color class in System.Windows.Media *is* equivalent on ARGB 'System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255) == System.Windows.Media.Colors.White' does equal true

Answer (score 5):

To add to Nick's (correct) answer: if you *really* wanted, you could write your own `IEqualityComparer<Color>` implementation and use that in, e.g., any algorithms you may be writing that deal with colors, where you want flexibility when it comes to color equality determination.

You know, something like:

```
public class ColorComparer : IEqualityComparer<Color>
{
    public bool Equals(Color x, Color y)
    {
        return x.ToArgb() == y.ToArgb();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Color color)
    {
        return color.ToArgb();
    }
}
```